# Better way to cleanup after running a bunch of tests with pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I want to run two different tests one after other in two different pytest runs and then tie a cleanup function to always run after second test. But, there should also be flexibility to just run the cleanup functions only.

I achieved the interaction between first and second test using pytest cache. The first test does something and writes necessary data to pytest cache. The second test when run with a different pytest command reads from that cache and does something else. I am using self variable of test class as cache by doing set attributes and get attributes in few of the pytest hooks.

In this case, I show cleanup as a test but, I don't want to call it `test_` since it is not a test and the results of this shouldn't be shown to user.

```py
# filename test_cases.py
class TestCase1:
    @pytest.mark('one')
    def test_one(self, fixture1):
        # fixture1.y = 1
        self.x = 1
        assert self.x + fixture1.y == 2

    @pytest.mark('two')
    def test_two(self, fixture2):
        # fixture2.y = 2
        self.x += fixture2.y
        assert self.x == 3

    @pytest.mark('cleanup')
    @pytest.mark('two')
    @pytest.mark.run('after=test_two')
    def test_cleanup(self, fixture):
        # Let's say this cleans stuff 
        fixture.y = 0
```

These series of commands would run the full tests.

`pytest test_cases.py -m "one"`

Collected 1 test... (test_one)

`pytest test_cases.py -m "two"`

Collected 2 tests..  (test_two and cleanup)

In the second command, it shows it as two tests and that is what the whole problem is. Is there anyway to exclude the cleanup from results but execute the cleanup part?

Or is there anyway the same could be achieved by changing `test_cleanup` to just `cleanup`? The catch here, is that cleanup function obviously is different for different test cases including the fixtures it takes as arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I think the cleanup should be part of your `fixture2`. Take advantage of a [fixture teardown](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code) using the `yield` statement instead of `return`:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def fixture2():
    # Create your fixture data
    value = 'whatever object the fixture is supposed to create'

    yield value

    # Perform cleanup on the data when the test function exits
```

Comment: After further thought, we changed the design to move away from this class type tests to simple function with fixtures for teardown. But that means, we need a new fixture for every test. Is it a good practice to have a fixture to be used only once and have a lot of such fixtures?

Comment: @manji369 No, that doesn't sound like a good idea. However, it's hard to propose an alternative without knowing what your fixtures do and how they generate the object that is supposed to be cleaned up.

Comment: To give more context, each of these tests would be testing a separate feature of a product. So, every test could potentially create a different entity compared to other tests. Which probably suggests that we cannot do this without having a separate fixture. That's the reason, I added the test_cleanup function to the class in the first place (To accommodate specific cleanup functionality of specific feature).

Comment: @manji369 It doesn't seem like you even need fixtures because if each case is so specific, you can setup everything within the test functions in which case... what is the cleanup really supposed to be doing?

Comment: The cleanup is supposed to delete the entities created inside a product (through rest api calls). We are supposed to re-use the product for continuous integration testing. The problem with doing the cleanup inside test function is that, there are two test functions for each test case (test_one and test_two) and it's not always that we run both of them. Based on cmdline args, we are supposed to run cleanup after just test_one or after both test_one and test_two are run.